# Resolving betrothals 'stuck' due opinion change

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I arranged a matrilineal marriage with some interesting claimant. By the time kids came of age, the husband-to-be went up in the line of succession and now his liege will not accept marriage proposal because the guy is 'too high in the line of succession'.
Neither will he suggest it himself.
Can I somehow force the marriage? Can I exit the betrothal without getting 'dishonored betrothal commitment' in my face? Can I get the dishonor on the  other guy?
As of now my bride is doomed to die childless and not benefit the house.

Comment: How high are we talking about here? If he isn't among the heirs or pretenders, you can buy a favor and force the marriage

Comment: I'd only betroth pretenders :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, from my own experience it's only matter of time before AI liege will suggest marriage himself, even if current opinion and succession line situation indicated it is impossible. It happened to me multiple times - most notable situation playing as a Duke of Greater Poland, having my daugther married matrilineally to HRE heir, becoming empress in the same year.

EDIT: Actually I had situation when bethrotal got locked due to husband-to-be becoming knight of military order. I've just broken the bethrotal, it's better to lose some opinion and try another bethrotal instead of losing benefit of marriage on one of your family members.

Comment: Yes, but AI would try to scam and suggest a regular marriage instead..

Comment: I've read about some people experiencing following thing (maybe it's happening all the time, but I missed it somehow) - when AI suggest marriage after bethrotal you get notification about it and sometimes you get 2 different notifications, first with 'scam' and second with original terms.

Comment: Found the original topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/CrusaderKings/comments/459un0/when_you_arrange_a_betrothal_but_the_other_party/